# Android: How the Columns of Tablerow Estimated while adding Multiple Table rows into Table Layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a table Layout.

**Like this**

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/PDT_LIST_TABLELAYOUT_EVEN"
    android:background="@drawable/tablelayout_border_even"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
</TableLayout>
```

Now I add multiple rows in this `TableLayout`. While adding I am facing a problem where the columns stretch between table rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **[stretchColumns - TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html,)**:

```
<TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="*">
```